# Font shape TU/lmss/m/sc not available with newly updated "newpxtext"

Tags: fonts, warnings

After a recent update to my TeX Live 2021 distribution, I'm getting the following kind of warning message in an old document:

```
Font shape `TU/lmss/m/sc' in size <10> not available
(Font)  Font shape `TU/lmr/m/sc' tried instead.
```

which resulted in that the title of the document (which is in `sffamily` and `scshape`) looks different compare with the earlier result. Is there some way to fix this?

Below is a MWE:

```
%! TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{newpxtext}

\begin{document}

\textsf{\textsc{Some Text}}

\end{document}
```

Below is the log:

```
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2021-11-22> (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count179
\c@section=\count180
\c@subsection=\count181
\c@subsubsection=\count182
\c@paragraph=\count183
\c@subparagraph=\count184
\c@figure=\count185
\c@table=\count186
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen138
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/newpx/newpxtext.sty
Package: newpxtext 2021/12/07 v1.501(Michael Sharpe) latex and unicode latex support for TeXGyrePagellaX
 `newpxtext' v1.501, 2021/12/07 Text macros taking advantage of TeXGyre Pagella and its extensions (msharpe) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2021/04/29 v2.0v Standard LaTeX package
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for T1+lmr on input line 112.
 (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/t1lmr.fd
File: t1lmr.fd 2015/05/01 v1.6.1 Font defs for Latin Modern
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifxetex.sty
Package: ifxetex 2019/10/25 v0.7 ifxetex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
 (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2019/10/25 v1.5 ifluatex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
Package: xkeyval 2020/11/20 v2.8 package option processing (HA)
 (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
\XKV@toks=\toks16
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks17
 (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))
\XKV@depth=\count187
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count188
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty
Package: textcomp 2020/02/02 v2.0n Standard LaTeX package
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.tex
\integerpart=\count189
\decimalpart=\count190
)
Package: xstring 2021/07/21 v1.84 String manipulations (CT)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2020/11/24 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/carlisle/scalefnt.sty)
LaTeX Font Info:    Setting zplLF sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Setting zplTLF sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Setting zplOsF sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Setting zplTOsF sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 24.
\zpl@cnt=\count191
 (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2021-11-22 L3 programming layer (loader) 
 (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-xetex.def
File: l3backend-xetex.def 2021-12-14 L3 backend support: XeTeX
 (|extractbb --version)
\c__kernel_sys_dvipdfmx_version_int=\count192
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count193
\g__color_backend_stack_int=\count194
\g__graphics_track_int=\count195
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box50
\g__pdf_backend_object_int=\count196
\g__pdf_backend_annotation_int=\count197
\g__pdf_backend_link_int=\count198
))
Package: xparse 2021-11-12 L3 Experimental document command parser
)
Package: fontspec 2020/02/21 v2.7i Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
 (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-xetex.sty
Package: fontspec-xetex 2020/02/21 v2.7i Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
\l__fontspec_script_int=\count199
\l__fontspec_language_int=\count266
\l__fontspec_strnum_int=\count267
\l__fontspec_tmp_int=\count268
\l__fontspec_tmpa_int=\count269
\l__fontspec_tmpb_int=\count270
\l__fontspec_tmpc_int=\count271
\l__fontspec_em_int=\count272
\l__fontspec_emdef_int=\count273
\l__fontspec_strong_int=\count274
\l__fontspec_strongdef_int=\count275
\l__fontspec_tmpa_dim=\dimen139
\l__fontspec_tmpb_dim=\dimen140
\l__fontspec_tmpc_dim=\dimen141
 (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2021/04/29 v2.0v Standard LaTeX package
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))
LaTeX Info: Redefining \textsl on input line 423.
 (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/realscripts/realscripts.sty
Package: realscripts 2016/02/13 v0.3d Access OpenType subscripts and superscripts
\subsupersep=\dimen142
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \textsu on input line 490.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \oldstylenums on input line 568.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \liningnums on input line 570.
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/newpx/TeXGyrePagellaX.fontspec)
Requested font "[TeXGyrePagellaX-Regular.otf]/OT" at 9.99997pt
 -> /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/newpx/TeXGyrePagellaX-Regular.otf
Requested font "[TeXGyrePagellaX-Regular.otf]/OT" at 10.00003pt
 -> /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/newpx/TeXGyrePagellaX-Regular.otf
Requested font "[TeXGyrePagellaX-Regular.otf]/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;" at 10.00003pt
 -> /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/newpx/TeXGyrePagellaX-Regular.otf
Requested font "[TeXGyrePagellaX-Bold.otf]/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;" at 10.00003pt
 -> /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/newpx/TeXGyrePagellaX-Bold.otf
Requested font "[TeXGyrePagellaX-Italic.otf]/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;" at 10.00003pt
 -> /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/newpx/TeXGyrePagellaX-Italic.otf
Requested font "[TeXGyrePagellaX-Slanted.otf]/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;" at 10.00003pt
 -> /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/newpx/TeXGyrePagellaX-Slanted.otf
Requested font "[TeXGyrePagellaX-BoldItalic.otf]/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;" at 10.00003pt
 -> /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/newpx/TeXGyrePagellaX-BoldItalic.otf
Requested font "[TeXGyrePagellaX-BoldSlanted.otf]/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;" at 10.00003pt
 -> /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/newpx/TeXGyrePagellaX-BoldSlanted.otf

Package fontspec Info: Font family 'TeXGyrePagellaX(0)' created for font
(fontspec)             'TeXGyrePagellaX' with options [Ligatures = TeX,Scale =
(fontspec)             1,Extension = .otf,SmallCapsFeatures={RawFeature =
(fontspec)             +pcap, },Ligatures=TeX,Extension = .otf,UprightFont =
(fontspec)             TeXGyrePagellaX-Regular,BoldFont =
(fontspec)             TeXGyrePagellaX-Bold,ItalicFont =
(fontspec)             TeXGyrePagellaX-Italic,BoldItalicFont =
(fontspec)             TeXGyrePagellaX-BoldItalic,SlantedFont =
(fontspec)             TeXGyrePagellaX-Slanted,BoldSlantedFont =
(fontspec)             TeXGyrePagellaX-BoldSlanted,Numbers =
(fontspec)             {Monospaced,Lining},UprightFont = *-Regular,ItalicFont
(fontspec)             = *-Italic,SlantedFont = *-Slanted,BoldFont =
(fontspec)             *-Bold,BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic,BoldSlantedFont=
(fontspec)             *-BoldSlanted].
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)              This font family consists of the following NFSS
(fontspec)             series/shapes:
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)             - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->s*[1]"[TeXGyrePagellaX-Regular.otf]/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;+tnum;+lnum;mapping=tex-text;"
(fontspec)             - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->s*[1]"[TeXGyrePagellaX-Regular.otf]/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;+tnum;+lnum;+smcp;+pcap;mapping=tex-text;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold' (b/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->s*[1]"[TeXGyrePagellaX-Bold.otf]/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;+tnum;+lnum;mapping=tex-text;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold small caps'  (b/sc) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->s*[1]"[TeXGyrePagellaX-Bold.otf]/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;+tnum;+lnum;+smcp;+pcap;mapping=tex-text;"
(fontspec)             - 'italic' (m/it) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->s*[1]"[TeXGyrePagellaX-Italic.otf]/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;+tnum;+lnum;mapping=tex-text;"
(fontspec)             - 'italic small caps'  (m/scit) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->s*[1]"[TeXGyrePagellaX-Italic.otf]/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;+tnum;+lnum;+smcp;+pcap;mapping=tex-text;"
(fontspec)             - 'slanted' (m/sl) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->s*[1]"[TeXGyrePagellaX-Slanted.otf]/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;+tnum;+lnum;mapping=tex-text;"
(fontspec)             - 'slanted small caps'  (m/scsl) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->s*[1]"[TeXGyrePagellaX-Slanted.otf]/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;+tnum;+lnum;+smcp;+pcap;mapping=tex-text;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold italic' (b/it) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->s*[1]"[TeXGyrePagellaX-BoldItalic.otf]/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;+tnum;+lnum;mapping=tex-text;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold italic small caps'  (b/scit) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->s*[1]"[TeXGyrePagellaX-BoldItalic.otf]/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;+tnum;+lnum;+smcp;+pcap;mapping=tex-text;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold slanted' (b/sl) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->s*[1]"[TeXGyrePagellaX-BoldSlanted.otf]/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;+tnum;+lnum;mapping=tex-text;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold slanted small caps'  (b/scsl) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->s*[1]"[TeXGyrePagellaX-BoldSlanted.otf]/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;+tnum;+lnum;+smcp;+pcap;mapping=tex-text;"

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `TU/TeXGyrePagellaX(0)/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 10.0pt on input line 6.
Requested font "[TeXGyrePagellaX-Regular.otf]/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;+tnum;+lnum;mapping=tex-text;" at 10.0pt
 -> /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/newpx/TeXGyrePagellaX-Regular.otf
 (./sf-font-test.aux)
\openout1 = `sf-font-test.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for TS1+cmr on input line 6.
 (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd
File: ts1cmr.fd 2019/12/16 v2.5j Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.

Package fontspec Info: Adjusting the maths setup (use [no-math] to avoid
(fontspec)             this).

\symlegacymaths=\mathgroup4
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `legacymaths' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/cmr/bx/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \acute on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \grave on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \ddot on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \tilde on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \bar on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \breve on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \check on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \hat on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \dot on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \mathring on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \colon on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Gamma on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Delta on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Theta on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Lambda on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Xi on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Pi on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Sigma on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Upsilon on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Phi on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Psi on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Omega on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \mathdollar on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `operators' on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `TU' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `normal' on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> TU/TeXGyrePagellaX(0)/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `TU' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `bold' on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> TU/TeXGyrePagellaX(0)/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  TU/TeXGyrePagellaX(0)/m/n --> TU/TeXGyrePagellaX(0)/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> TU/TeXGyrePagellaX(0)/m/it on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> TU/TeXGyrePagellaX(0)/b/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/n --> TU/lmss/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> TU/lmtt/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  TU/TeXGyrePagellaX(0)/m/n --> TU/TeXGyrePagellaX(0)/b/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/it --> TU/TeXGyrePagellaX(0)/b/it on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/bx/n --> TU/lmss/b/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> TU/lmtt/b/n on input line 6.
Requested font "[lmsans10-regular]:mapping=tex-text;" at 10.0pt
 -> /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmsans10-regular.otf


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/lmss/m/sc' in size <10> not available
(Font)              Font shape `TU/lmr/m/sc' tried instead on input line 8.

Requested font "[lmromancaps10-regular]:mapping=tex-text;" at 10.0pt
 -> /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmromancaps10-regular.otf
```

Comment: I get no warning. Show your log-file.

Comment: I'm afraid that the last update to `newpxtext` as a few bugs.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The content of my log-file is added.

Comment: ah sorry I ignored the xelatex indication.

Comment: @egreg why should that be a new bug? newpxtext never set sans serif, didn't it? And the warning is what you get without newpxtext too.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That's possibie; on the other hand there are other bugs.

Comment: @Jinwen I tried with XeLaTeX from TeX Live 2020 and the warning is not show, but T1 encoded fonts were used, which was dubious, to say the least. No `fontspec` loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With previous versions of `newpxtext` you didn't get OpenType fonts:

```
<ec-qhvr-sc@9.36pt(TFM:ec-qhvr-sc)(Encoding:q-ec-sc.enc)
pdf_font>> Simple font "qhvr.pfb" enc_id=<q-ec-sc.enc,3> opened at font_id=<ec-qhvr-sc,0>.
><zpl-Regular-tlf-t1@9.96pt(TFM:zpl-Regular-tlf-t1)(Encoding:ntx-ec-tlf.enc)
pdf_font>> Simple font "zplr.pfb" enc_id=<ntx-ec-tlf.enc,4> opened at font_id=<zpl-Regular-tlf-t1,1>.
>](qhvr.pfb[Type1])(zplr.pfb[Type1])
```

With the new version, `fontspec` is used and TeX Gyre PagellaX is used as the main font, but no sans serif font is chosen. Thus you get Latin Modern Sans, that has no small caps sans serif.

You need to declare a sans serif font, for instance TeX Gyre Heros.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{newpxtext}

\setsansfont{texgyreheros}[
  Scale=MatchLowercase,
  UprightFont=*-regular,
  BoldFont=*-bold,
  ItalicFont=*-italic,
  BoldItalicFont=*-bolditalic,
]

\begin{document}

Xyz \textsf{\textsc{Some Text}}

\end{document}
```

[image]